# how to display content of custom post types on index page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been trying to display content that is coming from custom post types on homepage but no luck.

index.php

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'HomepageContents',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
);
  
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
 <h1> <?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php the_content(); ?>
                               

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

functions.php

```
// Homepage  Custom Post Type
function homepage_content_init() {
    // set up Homepage Content labels
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'HomepageContents',
        'singular_name' => 'HomepageContent',
        'add_new' => 'Add New Homepage Content',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Homepage Content',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Homepage Content',
        'new_item' => 'New Homepage Content',
        'all_items' => 'All Homepage Content',
        'view_item' => 'View Homepage Content',
        'search_items' => 'Search Homepage Contents',
        'not_found' =>  'No Homepage Contents Found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Homepage Contents found in Trash', 
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Homepage Contents',
    );
    
    // register post type
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'homepage_content'),
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-randomize',
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'trackbacks',
            'custom-fields',
            'comments',
            'revisions',
            'thumbnail',
            'author',
            'page-attributes'
        )
    );
    register_post_type( 'homepage_content', $args );
    
    // register taxonomy
    register_taxonomy('homepage_content_category', 'homepage_content', array('hierarchical' => true, 'label' => 'Category', 'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'homepage-content-category' )));
}
add_action( 'init', 'homepage_content_init' );
```

I would like to publish content that is being published on  custom post types in homepage or index.php, and content should only be one, i.e the way single.php display its content
Thanks indavance

Comment: Have you tried `post_type => "homepage_content"`?

Answer (score 0):

The custom post type name must be lowercase alphanumeric characters, It can contain dashes and underscores only and must not exceed 20 characters.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#parameters

You need to update the register_post_type() name to something like that.

```
function homepage_content_init() {
    // set up Homepage Content labels
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'homepage-contents',
    ...
```

and update the posts query to the same name.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'homepage-contents',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
);
```